# accessing a backgrounded applications stdin/stdout with php

Tags: php

I want php to execute a unix application in the background, and have access to its stdin/stdout similar to how subprocess can in python ...is this possible? if so how?

Comment: `popen` & `proc_open` are your best bets when you need control over the pipes.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely exectute an external program 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

You can execture aPart of PHP's CLI interface are three "streams" with which you can interact in more or less the same way as you would a file resource returned from fopen(). The streams are identified with the strings:

php://stdin (read)
php://stdout (write)
php://stderr (write)

With the PHP 4.3.0+ CLI binary, these three streams are automatically available, identified with the constants STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR respectively. Here's how I can use the STDOUT to fix the above script so that it behaves correctly on Windows:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ( $i < 10 ) {
   // Write some output
   fwrite(STDOUT, $i."\n");
   sleep(1);
   $i++;
}
?>
```

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/php-command-line-1

**PK**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: `exec('unix_app | python_script > /dev/null &');`

EDIT:

Just read your question again and realized you don't want to pipe into a Python script. If you start the process in the background your PHP script will go on to execute the rest of itself and it won't be able to receive the STDIN/OUT. You could pipe it into a different PHP script like in my example above though and then you'll have access to STDIN again.